# Error: multiple types in one declaration

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks and Mingw32 with the SDL libraries. The error appears at line 13 of my code (commented below).

After some searching I believed it to be a missing semicolon(;), this doesn't appear to be the case here though. Additional research threw up the fact that it may be an error in an include file.

Unfortunately there are no errors in the includes and even when the include is commented out this error persists. When the enum block is commented out the error jumps to the end of the class declaration.

```
#ifndef _TILE_H_
#define _TILE_H_

#include "Define.h"

enum
{
    TILE_TYPE_NONE = 0,
    TILE_TYPE_GROUND,
    TILE_TYPE_RAMPUP,
    TILE_TYPE_RAISED,
    TILE_TYPE_RAMPDOWN
}; //error occurs here (line 13)

class Tile
{
public:
    int TileID;
    int TypeID;

public:
    Tile();
};

#endif
```

This actually started happening after adding a new class, however the new class is completely unrelated and does not use, include or inherit from the posted one at all.

Any advice or information would be really appreciated.

EDIT (adding Define.h):

```
#ifndef _DEFINE_H_
#define _DEFINE_H_

#define MAP_WIDTH 40
#define MAP_HEIGHT 40

#define TILE_SIZE 16

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 480

#endif
```

Comment: Did you mean to give your `enum` a name? (e.g. `enum e_tile_type { /*...*/};`)

Comment: look for the problems where your file is being included

Comment: What is the error message the compiler gives you?

Comment: and perhaps any issues (like missing semi) at the end of Define.h

Comment: The exact error message is the title (Error: multiple types in one declaration) as I said even when the file is not included (it's not yet used by this class) the error persists. Naming my enum has no effect.

Comment: Don't put `_` in front of your include guards.  Those names are reserved by the implementation.

Comment: I edited my code (and all other files) as you suggested. Thank you for pointing that out, you might be able to tell I'm fairly new to this. Unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: Yeah - I don't think it was the cause of your problem, or I would have written an answer.  I just thought I'd mention it as a tip for the future.

Comment: Fair enough, well thank you again. Suppose I keep researching and wait then.

Comment: Show where the file is being used!!!  Make sure it's really .hpp, not .cpp file where error is

Comment: where the "Tile.h" file is included, is there any header files included before that? Is the last one before "Tile.h" correct (i.e. all classes/structs/enums ends with semicolons etc.)?

Comment: @Anycorn: Good point! The error message pointed to a file that was OK. Actually the missing semicolon appeared in a different one, include in the main together with the one marked as erroneous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a file with this:

```
#include "Something.h"
#include "Tile.h"
```

In `Something.h`, you have this:

```
class Something {
    // ...
}
```

You are missing a semicolon, so the compiler sees:

```
class Something {
    // ...
}
enum {
};
```

Which is one declaration containing two types (a `class` and an `enum`), which is not allowed. The semicolon is required after `class`, `struct`, and `enum` because you can declare instances of a new type in the same declaration as the type:

```
struct Point { int x; int y; } my_point;
```

(Also, names starting with `_` and a capital letter are reserved. Use `TILE_H` instead of `_TILE_H_`.)

Comment: This was exactly the case, many miles away there was a missing semicolon and it was throwing everything out of wack. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @TechRomancer: My pleasure. I’ve made every C++ mistake in the book. :P

Answer (score 1):

When I comment out the include for Define.h, this code compiles fine for me using g++. That suggests that there may indeed be a problem in the included file, as you suggest. Perhaps you're missing a semicolon somewhere at the end of Define.h, or there is some other syntax problem there.

Comment: I edited the post to include Define.h as well. For me when the include is commented out in Tile.h the compiler still throws the same error.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there's no problem in Define.h. However, it only includes macros, no code, so perhaps the problem is actually in the code that appears right before Tile.h. You might try compiling the file where Tile.h is included with "gcc -E" or equivalent in order to see the preprocessor output.

Answer (score 0):

I called your first file `Tile.h` and created `Tile.cpp` as follows:

```
#include "Tile.h"

Tile::Tile()
{
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled on Ubuntu Linux with g++:

> $ g++ Tile.cpp -o Tile

I received neither a compilation nor runtime error (same for `gcc`).  Your problem is somewhere else--either in `#include`d files you're not showing us, or some kind of platform-specific naming conflict.  I'd try progressively renaming everything until the problem goes away.

Edit: Your original code unaltered in this case.